# how to use scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment in tensorflow or keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

first time posting here ! If my question is lacking anything please tell me and I'll fix it !

Facebook recently released DETR, an object detection model using transformers ! The model is implemented with Pytorch and I'm trying to implement the loss function where Hungarian algorithm is involved but with Keras and Tensorflow as a custom loss function for Keras model. In the original implementation from Facebook, it's line 81-82 in https://github.com/facebookresearch/detr/blob/master/models/matcher.py

In order to use numpy and classic python function, I used:

```
    def hungarian_loss(losses):
        row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(losses)
        idx = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(row_ind, col_ind)]
        return idx

    # dist loss is a 5x5 matrix, and idx is 5x2 indexes
    idx = tf.py_function(func=hungarian_loss, inp=[dist_loss], Tout=tf.int32)
    min_val = tf.gather_nd(dist_loss, idx)
    return K.mean(min_val)
```

But I got :

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Inner dimensions of output shape must match inner dimensions of updates shape. Output: [5,5] updates: [5]
```

Is it because I'm trying to use something that wasn't a tf.Tensor as loss ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work for you? See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function

```
@tf.function
def tf_linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix):
    return tf.numpy_function(func=linear_sum_assignment,inp=[cost_matrix],Tout=[tf.int64,tf.int64])
```

Comment: This got the algorithm running for me, but I'm getting "no gradients" error when I try to train. I suspect it's `linear_sum_assignment` being used in my loss function, but I know I've seen examples of Hungarian algorithm being used in losses before. Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: @Engineero This is a late comment, but if you want gradients then you'll need the algorithm to be implemented in your auto-grad package. I.e. if tensorflow, then implement linear_sum_assignment in TF, same with torch and whatnot. And whether or not the function has a well-defined "backwards" component will depend on the algorithm itself.